# Copy and paste commands with WPF buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, copy-paste

I have created a toolbar that has buttons.

Of the buttons 3 of them are cut copy and paste. I set the command of each of those buttons to cut copy and paste on the properties but when I go run the program none of the buttons are even clickable. Are they disabled I'm guessing? I'm trying to copy and paste from textbox to textbox in a tabcontrol. Any help is appreciated.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="textBoxCommands">
  <Setter Property="Content" 
          Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                          Path=Command.Text}" />
  <Setter Property="CommandTarget" 
          Value="{Binding ElementName=textBox}" />
</Style>

<Button x:Name="btnCut" 
        Click="btnCut_Click">
  <Image Source="Icons/Cut.png" ToolTip="Cut" />
</Button>
<Button x:Name="btnCopy" 
        Click="btnCopy_Click" 
        Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"
        Style="{StaticResource textBoxCommands}">
  <Image Source="Icons/Copy.png" ToolTip="Copy" />
</Button>
<Button x:Name="btnPaste" 
        Click="btnPaste_Click" 
        Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste"
        Style="{StaticResource textBoxCommands}" > 
  <Image Source="Icons/Paste.png" ToolTip="Paste" />
</Button>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can’t use command this way! The Command (in the way you use it) should be inside a `Menu` or `Toolbar`.
By the way, you don’t need those click event handler since you are going to use Commands!
I recommend you to try add `DelegateCommand` to the ViewModel and let that delegate call `ApplicationCommads`.

I highly recommend you to read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx
But as a quick solution for you try the following (important: remember that you need to have some text selected in your `TextBox` then `Copy` and `Cut` will be enabled):

```
<StackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">

  <ToolBar>
    <Button Content="Cut" Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" Height="23" Width="75"/>
    <Button Content="Copy" Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" Height="23" Width="75"/>
    <Button Content="Paste" Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" Height="23" Width="75"/>
  </ToolBar>

  <TextBox Height="23" Name="textBox1" Width="120"/>

</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand what those commands can be used for. I feel stupid asking this question but I'm new to all this. what is viewMode?

Comment: It was not a stupid question! Sorry I had a typo it was “ViewModel” (I had written ViewMode).   I added some code to my answer

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose you are trying to achieve I would suggest using a togglebutton.

Also the button would be clickable as and when they are supposed to. 
For example

- Paste button gets clickable only when there is something to paste.
- Cut/Copy Button gets clickable when there something selected in RTB.

Have a look at all the [ApplicationCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.aspx) at msdn. You can implement them as easily as:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="PasteBtn" Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste"/>
<ToggleButton x:Name="CutBtn"   Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut"/>
<ToggleButton x:Name="CopyBtn"  Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"/>
```