# Using commands in wpf is not working properly for a button

Tags: c#, wpf

There is a button in the following `xaml` code:

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="First" Content="First" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="40,91,0,67" />
```

In the constructor of the window I have assigned `ApplicationCommands.Copy` to the button.

```
public MainWindow()
{ 
    InitializeComponent();

    this.doc.Unit = DevExpress.Office.DocumentUnit.Point;

    this.First.Command = ApplicationCommands.Copy;
    First.CommandTarget = this.doc;
}
```

`this.doc` in the above code is a typical `richTextBox`.
The problem is that the button is always disabled. Why?

The entire `xaml` code is as follows:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:com="clr-namespace:DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Commands;assembly=DevExpress.RichEdit.v16.1.Core"
    xmlns:dxre="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/richedit" xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors" xmlns:ig="http://schemas.infragistics.com/xaml" xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="1000" x:Name="wnd">


<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="163*"  />
        <RowDefinition Height="60*"  />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <dxre:RichEditControl x:Name="doc" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,23" Unit="Point" ActiveViewType="PrintLayout"/>

    <!--<telerik:RadToggleButton 
        Content="B" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="False" Margin="10,32,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="26"/>-->

    <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="First" Content="First" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="40,91,0,67" />


</Grid></Window>
```

Comment: Can you show all the relevant XAML?  It might be that your button is in a container that is disabled for some reason.

Comment: @rory.ap actually I just have that button in my xaml code

Comment: So when you say "disabled" do you mean "grayed out"?  Or what?  Even if you just have the button, it would be in at least a Window control.

Comment: actually it is grayed and not working, it is visible. In winForms it was called disabled state.

Comment: Well, something you aren't showing is disabling it.  We can't really help you if you aren't showing all relevant code.  By default, the button would be enabled.

Comment: check the updates :)

Comment: Not sure.  What happens if you add "Enabled=True" to the button?

Comment: not working, I do not know the reason. it is not logical at all. the command does not work and there is no reason for that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563666/copy-and-paste-commands-with-wpf-buttons

Comment: Also somewhat similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641656/how-to-bind-applicationcommands-to-a-viewmodel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Button.Command` property is a type if `ICommand`, which includes a `CanExecute` method. When this method returns false the `Button` will be disabled.

I believe that's what's happening here, the `ApplicationCommands.Copy` command is returning false for `CanExecute`. Perhaps someone else can offer an explanation as to why this is in this case?

Are you able to use a `CommandBinding` as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753200(v=vs.110).aspx) to implement your own `CanExecute` event handler?

```
<Window x:Class="WCSamples.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="CloseCommand"
    Name="RootWindow"
    >
  <Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"
                    CanExecute="CanExecuteHandler"
                    />
  </Window.CommandBindings>
  <StackPanel Name="MainStackPanel">
    <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" 
            Content="Copy" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>

private void CanExecuteHandler(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // CanExecute logic in here.
    e.CanExecute = true;
}
```